# Sum two alias column in mysql

Tags: mysql

I tried to sum two alias column but failed, here's my query:

```
SELECT MAX(a.`score`) AS score1,SUM(c.`testscore`) AS score2,b.`first_name`,b.`last_name`,b.`picture` ,
 SUM(score1 + score2) AS grandtotal
FROM test AS a
INNER JOIN employees AS b
ON a.`id` = b.`id`
INNER JOIN game AS c
ON a.`id` = c.`id`

GROUP BY a.`id`;
```

Getting error: Unknown column 'score1 ' in 'field list'

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Use `MAX(a.score)` instead of `score1` and `SUM(c.testscore)` instead of  `score2` as the alias are unknown in the query

Comment: @RomainBar I tried SUM(MAX(a.score) + c.testscore) as grandTotal but failed :/

Comment: Well, when you're ready.

Comment: what @Strawberry :S

Comment: try without sum, just MAX(a.score) + SUM(c.`testscore`)

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
SELECT MAX(a.`score`) AS score1,SUM(c.`testscore`) AS score2,b.`first_name`,b.`last_name`,b.`picture` ,
(MAX(a.`score`) + SUM(c.`testscore`)) AS grandtotal
FROM test AS a
INNER JOIN employees AS b
ON a.`id` = b.`id`
INNER JOIN game AS c
ON a.`id` = c.`id`

GROUP BY a.`id`;
```